# How to temporary disable map click event in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, events

How can I disable map click event?
My idea is to disable it when I am positioned with mouse over my popup container. After I move mouse out of it, I want that event to be enabled again. Something like this:

```
container=document.getElementById('popup')
container.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
                 //disable map click event
}

container.addEventListener('mouseout,function(){
                 //enable it again
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I usually use Leaflet, but here is some quick research. You can use [`getInteractions()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_PluggableMap-PluggableMap.html#getInteractions) on your map, find out the `click` event and then [`setActive(boolean)`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Interaction-Interaction.html#setActive) that interaction.

Comment: OpenLayers should do that automatically if you use an overlay to display your popup.

Comment: @Mike Yeah i know, but I am trying to present ext js tab panel inside popup and when i click on my tabs while overlay property stopEvent is set to true , tabs are not responding. When I change property to false and then click on tabs functionality is working, but its like I can click trough on map also and new popout comes in place where I clicked on tab. I Tried now  with ol.interaction.Select instance to setActive(false) under the condition that I am hovering over the popup container but it didn't help. I am out of ideas. I can put link here on different variation of problem

Comment: How are you making your tabs? Bootstrap tabs or something else..?

Comment: @rbkb ext.js library

Comment: You could try setting the overlay's stopEvent property to false and then adding an event handler on the tabs themselves. Within that handler call event.stopPropagation() to stop the event from bubbling further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a search box (which for historical reasons wasn't a control, simply a div above the map).  Mouse interactions on features were easy to disable and re-enable, but for map click events I resorted to setting and testing a mouseOver var.

```
var mouseOver = false;

searchBox.onmouseover = function() {
    map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction){interaction.setActive(false);});
    mouseOver = true;
};

searchBox.onmouseout = function() {
    map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction){interaction.setActive(true);});
    mouseOver = false;
};

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

    if (mouseOver) { return; }

    ...
    ...
    ...

};
```